# How can I keep my parameters escaped using Sytem.Uri?

Tags: .net, http

I have a redir page that takes some query parameters, notably a "page" parameter which, in turn, has its own query parameters.  A simplified version might look like this.

> http://www.example.com/redir.aspx?page=[escaped address]&two=2

The following test fails because the System.Uri constructor is unescaping my inner page's parameters. (kthx!)

```
Assert.AreEqual(
   "http://www.ex.com/redir.aspx?page=inner.htm%3Fone%3D1%26two%3D2&three=3",
   new Uri("http://www.ex.com/redir.aspx?page=inner.htm%3Fone%3D1%26two%3D2&three=3").ToString());
```

I'm actually getting http://www.ex.com/?page=inner.htm?one=1&two=2&three=3 which doesn't even look like a decent URI to me, what with the 2 question marks and don't really whose parameter that "three" is.  As you can see from the test, inner.htm has 2 parameters, one and two, and three is for redir.

Am I all wet?  Is this the right way to pass a URI to a URI?

Comment: How about `new Uri("http://www.ex.com/redir.aspx?" + Uri.EscapeDataString("page=inner.htm%3Fone%3D1%26two%3D2&three=3"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The following test fails because the System.Uri constructor is
>   unescaping my inner page's parameters.

No, the `Uri` constructor is doing the right thing. The test is failing because you're calling `Uri.ToString()`, which is [broken by design](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/278867/uri-tostring-returns-invalid-url-by-erroneously-urldecoding-each-argument).

[Don't use `Uri.ToString()`](http://code.logos.com/blog/2010/08/uritostring_must_die.html). Use [`Uri.AbsoluteUri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absoluteuri.aspx) instead.

```
// this works
Assert.AreEqual(
    "http://www.ex.com/redir.aspx?page=inner.htm%3Fone%3D1%26two%3D2&three=3",
    new Uri("http://www.ex.com/redir.aspx?page=inner.htm%3Fone%3D1%26two%3D2&three=3").AbsoluteUri);
```